# Explicit solution of vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-bundles

Suppose there are vectors $p_i,p_j,z$ and scalar $r$.

We have such following relation ship:
$$
z^Tp_i - z^T p_j = r^2
$$

How to solve the explicit solution of vector $z$?

Comment: $Z^T (p_i - p_j) = r^2$.  There are in general many solutions to this equation.  It just states that the projection of $z$ along the difference vector has a particular value $r^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black vector is $(p_i - p_j)$ and the plane is at a distance $r^2$ from the base of that vector.  The blue vectors are just a few of the infinite set of vectors with the same dot product with $(p_i - p_j)$.

[image]